# Where does Transmission save my torrent files?

Tags: transmission

I have a lot of torrents and currently I use [Transmission](https://transmissionbt.com/) as my torrent client.

However, there is a problem — After I change the folder name (which is important for me to organize my music folder), Transmission stops recognizing the files even though they remained the same.

I would like to switch to a different torrent client, but I can't find the torrent files. Where are they located?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Transmission stores your torrent files in your standard config folder, at `~/.config/transmission/torrents` where ~ is your home folder.

The .config folder is usually hidden. To get there, open the File Browser and go to your home folder. Choose View > Show Hidden Files in the menu, then look for ".config". In that folder you'll find transmission, and the rest should be pretty straight-forward.
(By the way, to find a file in a long list you can just start typing its name).

The torrent folder contains every *current* torrent, and it includes torrents downloaded from magnet links as well. You can just open those with another client and it will work right away.

Remember to turn Show Hidden Files back off later on, or you'll see a lot of strange looking files:

[image: Hidden Files Setting]

Comment: Given that transmission runs under `debian-transmission`, the home folder you refer to is most likely `/var/lib/transmission-daemon`. Check this with `grep transmission /etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 30):

## Check here too:

If you're daemonizing transmission on Ubuntu (using the package `transmission-daemon`) and using a gui then:

This data is stored in `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info` (requires root access to view, use `sudo` from the command line or install `nautilus-gksu`). Specifically, your torrents are in the directory `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/torrents`.

Comment: Any idea on how to change this default dir? just by looking at transmission's [configuration options](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/EditConfigFiles) I can't find out if that's possible.

Comment: @Chuim not sure, not actively using transmission anymore.

Comment: @Chuim Unfortunately, I see no way to set this location from the defaults provided by a fresh install of `transmission-daemon` on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

In complement for the daemonized transmission, you can check theses files :
`/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon` for changing user executing transmission,
`/etc/default/transmission-daemon` for finding `CONFIG_DIR="/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info"`

The "config_dir" `info` is a symbolic link to `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon` and here we can found another link `settings.json` to `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`

Now you can fully customize your transmission's directory structure

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command

```
ps ax | grep transmission
```

and it results with

```
/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
```

then you can try to edit the
*/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service*
file:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error --config-dir=/your/config-dir
```

The directories and files (e.g. settings.json) in */your/config-dir* has to have **rw** permission for **debian-transmission** user or group (the name depends on your distribution).

Follow this link for details:
https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?t=16642#p69968