# How to retrieve magnet link from Transmission?

Tags: file-sharing, transmission

How do I get the [magnet](https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?t=18154) links [from](https://askubuntu.com/q/123824/45156) Transmission?

I didn't [realize](https://askubuntu.com/q/1166544/45156) that this information was even stored.

I'd like to use just regular Transmission, rather than [remote](https://superuser.com/q/380497/55747).  What I've tried:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ transmission-remote -l -t 13 -i | grep magnet | sed -e "s/^ *Magnet: //"
[2019-08-19 20:21:45.080] transmission-remote:  (http://localhost:9091/transmission/rpc/) Couldn't connect to server
[2019-08-19 20:21:45.081] transmission-remote:  (http://localhost:9091/transmission/rpc/) Couldn't connect to server
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ transmission -l -t 13 -i | grep magnet | sed -e "s/^ *Magnet: //"
transmission: command not found
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
thufir@dur:~$
```

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem. Have you got any solution yet? Its surely possible to scrape them from transmission web interface but I wonder if there is an easier way to do that

Comment: for the time being I'm just going to swap hard drives, so no.  Do please document your efforts.  Sorry, very much a back-burner project.  If you ask your own question, that's fine, but do let me know.  Maybe unix/linux stack exchange?

Answer (score 1):

## With `transmission-show --magnet`

Call [`transmission-show`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/transmission-show.1.en) with the `--magnet` option to get the magnet link:

```
transmission-show --magnet 8fd3fac2bcea8809ac837dba076c37801b56e03d.torrent
```

This produces a link like this:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:8fd3fac2bcea8809ac837dba076c37801b56e03d&dn=FileNameOfTorrent
```

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123824/where-does-transmission-save-my-torrent-files) to get the location of your `.torrent` files. Since I used `transmission-daemon`, mine were in `/var/lib/transmission/.config/transmission-daemon/torrents/`.

Comment: How would we connect the name of the torrent, to the specific torrent file (<hash>.torrent)?

Comment: @Diagon: Do you see the torrent name when you run `transmission-show your.torrent`?

Comment: Got it, yes.  Thank you @matthias-braun